# ASP.NET Core - DI - Using Action<T> or IOption<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, extension-methods, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to understand the different between using `IOptions<T>` and `Action<T>` and when to use what.

I have a library that is using an extension method for `IServiceCollection` where I need to configure my service as well as configure a EF `DbContext`.

**Example:**

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 
{
    public static void AddModule(this IServiceCollection services, IOptions<SomeOptionsClass> options) {
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(contextOptions => contextOptions.UseSqlServer(SomeOptionsClass.ConnectionString));
    }
}
```

How do I get the `ConnectionString` property value from the `SomeOptionsClass`?

Comment: Not sure why the needs for IOptions here. provide some more context. Should be able to get the connection string from Configuration. IOptions is used for injecting setting into classes

Comment: What i'm trying to do is allow someone to manage their own configuration (appsettings.json) file but then when configuring my library I want them to pass the set configuration properties my library requires.

Comment: I could use Action<SomeOptionsClass> but then what is the correct way to get the value from the action? Is invoking the action the correct way of doing this? actionOptions?.Invoke(variable); ?

Comment: I am totally puzzled what you are actually asking here (maybe it is just me, though). If you are trying to reload configuration data, you can use [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options#reload-configuration-data-with-ioptionssnapshot). But I don't know what `Action<T>` has to do with any of this (or even if you are consistently referring to `Action<T>` or if you are referring to *action methods* here, too).

Comment: Hi @NightOwl888, I'm trying to understand the best what to get configuration options to my Extension method. I've seen a few projects, swagger for example uses an Action<T> in the AddSwaggerGen. I'm trying to understand why/when you would use Action<T> over IOptions<T>.

Comment: Be careful with `IOptions<T>`. Its use should be limited to the Composition Root, as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioptions-t).

Comment: there is also the reply to the article pointed by @Steven [here](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/is-ioptions-t-bad/), just to make better decision upon using IOptions<T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why the need for `IOptions<T>` here.

Should be able to get the connection string from Configuration (*appsetting*) during startup. `IOptions<T>` is usually used for injecting setting into classes

I suggest simplifying the API to expect the connection string

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection  {
    public static void AddModule(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) {
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(contextOptions => contextOptions.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    }
}
```

This would allow users more flexibility when configuring the module.

For example in the configure services in composition root you can access configuration and extract the connection string to be used as needed

```
//...

services.AddModule(Configuration["Appsettings Key Here"]);
```